# Error sending emails with Rails 4 & Devise (connection refused, port 25)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise, mailgun

I'be been having some massive issues getting emails to send. I've tried multiple ways of doing things; using gmail, mailgun, sendgrid, the mailgun gem etc, no luck at all. For some reason it's trying to send using port 25 although, as you can see below, I'm specifying port 587. The error I get is:

**Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):**

My development.rb file is as follows:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
  :port => 587,
  :api_key => 'key-5d321b99f722e71f759993ee41512b99',
  :user_name => 'postmaster@sandbox3ed8de9510c845c68bf0d867a8f25394.mailgun.org',
  :password => '(mailgun password)',
  :domain => 'sandbox3ed8de9510c845c68bf0d867a8f25394.mailgun.org',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I have looked around for solutions however none seem to solve the issue. I'm totally out of ideas.

entire Development.rb document:

```
    Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    user_name: "chris.edhogben@gmail.com",
    password: "<password>",
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: What is your exact version of rails?

Comment: Is there anything else in your app that changes action mailer settings?

Comment: I'm on rails 4.2. I don't believe there is anything else in the app that should change the action mailer settings. Is there anything I should search for to clarify this? I did have a mailgun gem installed, and a sendgrid gem, however I removed both.

Answer (score 4):

Try This configuration

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:  'localhost',
  port:     25,
  domain:   'exmaple.com',
      enable_starttls_auto: false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the below settigns in `production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = { 
    :address => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
    :port => 587,
    :user_name => 'postmaster@sandbox3ed8de9510c845c68bf0d867a8f25394.mailgun.org',
    :password => '(mailgun password)',
    :domain => 'sandbox3ed8de9510c845c68bf0d867a8f25394.mailgun.org',
    :authentication => :plain
  }
```

Comment: I've put this into production with my mailgun password and restarted my server, still the same error. Still trying to use port 25.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below settigns for gmail:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  user_name: "username",
  password: "password",
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

If you get SMTP authentication error , then click on http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha & enable it. It will enable google for registering new apps within 10 minutes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this however my issue is still the same: 
"Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25"

Comment: @edhog: Try the above setting  with gmail , if not works , then paste your complete development.rb with the used settings

Comment: I gave it a shot and got a password generated from google. It's still given me the same error: port 25. I believe I still encounter the same issue in production.rb. I've pasted my development.rb in full at the bottom of my original post.

Answer (score 2):

add same mail configuration in production.rb also.
Restart the server and check